# Counting conditional string partitions

Tags: java, algorithm

I need help writing a program that counts the number of partitions that can be made of a grid of letters satisfying the properties:

- The partition must consist of only two letters (so, if the grid contains letters A, B and C, the partition can only hold two of these)
- One of the two letters must all be adjacent to each other (this means that we must be able to transverse the entire region moving only up/down/left/right)
- The second letter must be contained in two or more regions
- A partition must not be contained in any other partition (this means that no subset of a partition also satisfies the properties of a partition)
- A partition CAN be the entire grid if necessary.

The input is a grid with dimensions N x N. I am given N on the first line.

```
**Example:** 
***
*Input:*

4
ABBC
BBBC
AABB
ABBC

***
*Output*
2
****
```

In this example, the first line, "4" tells us that there will be a 4x4 grid input next. The output **2** is determined from the number of subgrids that can be made satisfying the properties described above.
In this example, the two subgrids are:

```
ABB
BBB
AAB
ABB

***
and
***
BC
BC
BB
BC
***
```

Note that both subgrids contain only two distinct characters.

In the first subgrid, we are able to transverse all of the 'B' characters by only traveling up/down/left/right. There are two 'A' regions. So, the properties are satisfied

In the second subgrid, we can transverse all of the 'B' characters. We can not transverse all of the 'C' characters. So, the properties are satisfied.

Since there are two subgrids, the output is **2**.

---

**My thoughts**

I began by reading in the dimensions and looping through the grid. This is the code that I have as of right now:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class partition  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);      
        int dimensions = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0 ; i  < dimensions; i++) {
            for (int j = 0  ; j < dimensions; j++ ) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think that reading all of the characters into an array might be a good approach, but I am not sure of how I would proceed from there. Can someone please give me some suggestions? I believe coming up with an  effective algorithm will be the most difficult part of this.

Comment: This looks like a competition (or homework) problem. If it's from a competition that has already finished, please post a link to the source, so that people who don't want to help someone unfairly can contribute.

Comment: OK, try thinking of a "brute force" algorithm that will definitely give the right answer, though possibly not in the most efficient way. Describe this, and also its Big O time complexity, and then we'll look at possible improvements.

Comment: Hint: Think of how to test whether a *given* subrectangle satisfies the criteria. Then you can generate every possible subrectangle and test each one.

Comment: Would it work to check if e have two nonconsecutive occurences of a letter? This could tell me if there's two different areas for that letter.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by non-consecutive? If you mean that, for example, part of a row looks like `ABA`, this isn't enough, since it could be that those two `A`s are connected in some other way (e.g., by `AAA` in the next row).